# meaning of 'cinema'

Tags: vocabulary

The word 'cinema' is defined as a movie theater, films collectively, or the film-making industry. But I saw it in 'New Line Cinema'. Obviously, it means a film production company here. But why isn't this sense ever recorded in major dictionaries?

Comment: Because, aside from the *name* "New Line Cinema", nobody ever calls a film production company a "cinema". It's the same reason that "bakery" isn't listed as one of the meanings for the word "bread" in the dictionary, despite the fact that a large number of bakeries have names like "Main Street Bread".

Comment: This is another false question. The sense **is** given in AHD, Collins, and Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary. Why don't questioners check?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since when is the 'film production company' sense of cinema given in Collins and other dictionaries? Post the links if you can.

Comment: Of all the comments received so far, only Peter's is right to the point; the others are either irrelevant by citing the definitions I already know, or, like Edwin's, wouldn't bother to read my question carefully enough.

Comment: **cinema**:  The film or movie industry. [AHD] // **industry** - the people or companies engaged in a particular kind of commercial enterprise [WordNet 3.0] And although 'cinema' really refers to the industry as a whole, the transferred shade of meaning is transparent (if perhaps a little proprietorial). In fact, as 'New Line Cinema was established in 1967 by the then 27-year-old Robert Shaye as a film _distribution_ company', the name is quite appropriate.

Comment: . . .As they are faced with a proper noun in 'New Line Cinema', the dictionaries must decide on how far to spell out nuances of sub-lexemes in such idiosyncratic coinings. The senses of 'Music' as in 'Roxy Music' and 'Radio' as in 'Radio Merseyside' probably need a slight amount of deducing from dictionary definitions also.

Comment: Any other examples of words denoting an industry as a whole transferred to mean a single company？

Comment: The Collins Dictionary has one sense of radio defined as 'the broadcasting, content, etc. of sound radio programmes'. So it's hard to argue that'Radio Merseyside'is transferred from the industry sense, rather than from the content sense.

Comment: Apollyon, the word *cinema* is common in England and the rest of the UK, meaning somewhere that people pay to watch films. *Movie theater* is not used in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to speculate about the reasons others hold for their actions. But *cinema* is far more often used in the "movie theatre" sense than for "film" itself. Dictionaries will include definitions that apply in the majority of uses, and will only include rarer uses if they can justify the use of space.

However, OED has no space restrictions and does include the second sense:

> **a.** A popular abbreviation, and now the usual form, of **cinematograph** *n.*; hence (short for *cinema hall n.* at Compounds 1, etc.), a building in which cinematographic films are exhibited.
>
> **b.** Cinema films collectively, esp. considered as an art-form; the production of such films. Also, material suitable for presentation in or as a cinema film.

Answer (score 2):

Cinema is also shorthand for cinematography, which wikipedia introduces as:

> Cinematography (from Greek: κίνημα, kinema "movements" and γράφειν, graphein "to record") is the art or science of motion picture photography.[1] It is the technique of movie photography, including both the shooting and development of the film.[2] The cinematographer could also be referred to as the film director's main visual collaborator.[3]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematography